# My app is in pending review for long time

Tags: application-development

I have submitted a chess puzzle app before 4 days. I created the app in java platform. As I do not know how to package it, I have submitted my app in .jar format. Till now my app is in pending review stage. Please let me know when will they process it.

My app name:      Knight's Tour
Submitted date:   Oct-31st-2012
Submitted format: .jar

Answer (score 0):

Since you submitted your app without packaging, you have to wait more. Because ARB have to  package and test your app. :)